# Small white space showing after the image

Tags: html, css

So I have that small white space after the image, how can I fix that?
Here is code of my class:

```
.hero-image2 {
  background-image: url("/assets/kava.jpeg");
  width:33%;
  right:0px;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

And here is the other class which is on left side:

```
.tekst2 {
 width: 67%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}
```

Here is what it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmS1K.jpg)

Comment: share your HTML

Comment: width 33.33% maybe

Comment: Can you convert this to a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce the issue here?

Comment: you have to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because maybe there is some element after the image which is creating this space.

Comment: `background-size:cover;` - if the space is caused by wrong proportions.

Comment: I can see no problem there, here is a jsfiddle for your question: jsfiddle.net/yfz0689g

Comment: I edited my code, and added other class and how that space looks like.

Comment: Okay so you'd like to use the whole height and you've got this little space down there. That's you're problem, right?

Comment: Yeah that's true!

Answer (score -2):

You can give negative margin bottom value for example margin-bottom=-30px;

Comment: **Opinion**: Try and avoid negative margins to fix issues like this if there's an alternative. Unless used correctly, it might affect the layout in ways you aren't expecting.